# What is the output of text decoder

Tags: unicode, decode, encode, codec, python-unicode

Hi I know it sounds a dumb question but it actually confuses me like what does text decoder give? 
I can understand with respect to audio/video decoder that it gives the samples that can be converted to analog data that comes out from output devices.

But I actually cannot understand that what text decoder gives and how any decoded text can be taken to encode with any encoding schemes.

Answer (score 1):

You assume there is no encoding scheme for text. This is wrong. There are dozens. For example, the character `噸` as octet sequences in a few popular encodings:

- UTF-8: 0xe5 0x99 0xb8
- UTF-16-BE: 0x56 0x78
- GB18030: 0x87 0x8d
- US-ASCII: impossible, the character does not belong to the encoding's character repertoire
- Latin9: impossible, the character does not belong to the encoding's character repertoire

Another one: `ß`

- UTF-8: 0xc3 0x9f
- UTF-16-BE: 0x00 0xdf
- GB18030: 0x81 0x30 0x89 0x38
- US-ASCII: impossible, the character does not belong to the encoding's character repertoire
- Latin9: 0xdf

Another one: `u`

- UTF-8: 0x75
- UTF-16-BE: 0x00 0x75
- GB18030: 0x75
- US-ASCII: 0x75
- Latin9: 0x75

Verify this manually! Download this web page, open it in a hex editor and try to find the UTF-8 sequences above.

**A text decoder takes the octets as input and turns them into usable text again.**

You probably haven't noticed this concept yet because you only worked with Latin characters so far, and although you neglected to care about text encoding and decoding everything worked out without apparent problems. This is because many encodings are somewhat backward compatible with granddaddy US-ASCII as you can see from the last example.

Python, like many other programming languages, adheres to Unicode to a high degree, and so does its text processing model. The clear separation of *text as a series of characters or graphemes* (within the programming language) and *encoded text as a series of octets* (outside of the programming language, in disk files, standard I/O streams, databases, command-line arguments, environment variables, network sockets etc.) is very necessary, otherwise you get the wrong result when you try to determine the size of text, or try to line-break it.

A text codec is the precise boundary between these worlds.